# SEO friendly URL's in my language selector

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the URL's so they are SEO friendly URL's in my language selector.

At the moment if i change languages the URL looks like this

```
mydomain.com/index?lang=en
```

I want it to be something like

```
mydomain.com/index/en
```

I want it to stay on the choosen language no matter what page i navigate to

This is my .htaccess rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php?lang=$2
```

This is my initialization file

```
<?php
$languages = array('en', 'ru');

$get_lang = Input::get('lang');

if(isset($get_lang) === true && in_array($get_lang, $languages) === true) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $get_lang;
} else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}

include 'lang/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';
?>
```

This is my HTML mark up

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="?lang=en"><img src="assets/images/flags/gb.png" width="16" height="11" alt="EN">ENGLISH</a></li>
    <li><a href="?lang=ru"><img src="assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="RU">RUSSIAN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Well this is what i have and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteRule does not fit your needs because it does not capture the language code ($2 does not exist). For your URL structure, the rule should be like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([a-z]{2})$ $1.php?lang=$2
```

Where `$1` is the page name and `$2` the language code.

If you want to set this URL structure up, you'll also have to adapt your links targets. Basically, you'll have to add the content of `$_SESSION['lang']` at the end of each `href`.

**To switch from a language to another**,

- If no base url is set in the header `<base>` tag, `<a href="en">...</a>` or `<a href="./en">...</a>` should work
- If it doesn't work, it's probably because a base url is set in the `<base>` tag. For example, il the base URL set is http://domain/, when you target `./th`, it will do `http://domain/th` instead of `http://domain/currentpage/th` (and Apache will probably say that `th.php` does not exist, du to URL rewriting). In this case, you'll have either to remove base tag, or to change it to include the page path.

The painful operation, if you have a lot of links, can be to add the language code at the end of each `href`. Some lines of thought :

- `http://domain/lang/page` can be easier to set up than `http://domain/page/lang`, because if the base tag is not set or contains the language code, you'd not have to specify the language code in each link target URL
- adding the code language in href's in JavaScript, if you have envisioned it, is not an option because search engines will not see it
- depending on your architecture (is the content purely static ?), it can be easier to set multiple sub-domains up : we often see `http://lang.domain.com` for example. But it can dilute the ranking of the website in search engines, because it's not seen as an unique domain.
- defining a PHP function to generate the `href`'s can be useful to easily change URL's structure. We often see PHP frameworks offering helpers for that.

Comment: Yeh, but all i am getting is `/th.php was not found on this server`

Comment: I want it to stay on the choosen language no matter what page i navigate to `mydomain.com/index/en` etc etc

Comment: I improved my answer.